# relacionar duas tabelas

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Gostaria de saber como faço pra relacionar duas tabelas em bancos de dados diferentes de modo que toda vez que o valor na tabela banco1.dbo.tabela id1 vai ser mudado tambem no banco2.dbo.tabela id1, modificando de acordo a linha(id) a qual está sendo modificado

a questão é que estão assim as tabelas

tabela1
id - coluna2 - coluna3 - point
1 --- 0 ---------- 0 -------- 10
2 --- 0 ---------- 0 -------- 25

tabela2
id - coluna2 - coluna3 - coluna4 - bonus
1 ------ 0 -------- 0 ---------- 0 --------- ?
2 ------ 0 -------- 0 ---------- 0 --------- ?

eu queria que esse point passasse pro bonus sempre que fosse mudado, de acordo com a linha ali (id), então no caso se mudou aquele 25 ali na linha 2 será alterado também aqui na linha 2 da coluna bonus na tabela 2 é meio confusco, obrigado por responder

Comment: Talvez utilizando um `Trigger`.

Answer (score 1):

Desta forma deve conseguir o que pretende:

```
-- Descomentar apenas se a solução abaixo não resolver o problema
-- EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
-- GO
-- RECONFIGURE
-- GO
-- EXEC sp_configure 'nested triggers', 0
-- GO  
-- RECONFIGURE
-- GO

-- Alterar o "MyDataBase" para o nome da base de dados
ALTER DATABASE MyDataBase SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF
GO

CREATE TRIGGER tr_AtualizaID ON tabela1
AFTER UPDATE   
AS
    DECLARE @Id     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    DECLARE @Points FLOAT

    IF UPDATE(points)
    BEGIN
        SELECT  TOP 1 
                @Id     = id
            ,   @Points = points
        FROM    inserted

        UPDATE  tabela2
        SET     bonus   = @Points
            ,   origem  = 1
        WHERE   id      = @Id
    END
GO

CREATE TRIGGER tr_AtualizaID ON tabela2
AFTER UPDATE   
AS
    DECLARE @Id     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    DECLARE @Points FLOAT

    IF UPDATE(points)
    BEGIN
        SELECT  TOP 1 
                @Id     = id
            ,   @Points = points
        FROM    inserted

        UPDATE  tabela1
        SET     bonus   = @Points
            ,   origem  = 1
        WHERE   id      = @Id
    END
GO
```

Os comentários iniciais servem para, quando descomentado, evitar o aninhamento de *triggers*, mas só deve utilizar caso a solução de desativar a recursividade não funcionar.

Comment: @Merlin altere a sua questão e coloque lá esse código. Quanto mais detalhe sobre a questão, melhor!

Comment: eu coloquei abaixo um exemplo, mas nao ta saindo com a formataçao que eu queria, sou novo aqui no forum, nao sei usar ainda direito, obrigado pela atenção

Comment: Resposta alterada para corresponder ao cenário que indicou. Uma recomendação: altere a questão inicial ao invés de colocar uma nova resposta.

Comment: sim, agradeço de mais, funcionou perfeitamente pro que eu queria, se não for incômodo me tira mais uma dúvida, se eu fizer esse mesmo procedimento pra outra tabela, no caso pra tabela 2, pra caso editar a 1 tambem editar a 2(já esta funcionando), e caso editar a 2 tambem editar a 1(fiz mas deu um erro quando edita), eu acredito que seja por que um gatilho fica acionando o outro infinitamente? obrigado pela atenção

Comment: Aí vai ficar com um _loop_ nos _triggers_, por isso teria de fazer de outra forma. Mas quer atualizar qual coluna da `tabela1`?

Comment: seria pedir muito da minha parte te pedir uma ajuda nessa questão, não tenho esse conhecimento, eu já pesquisei por associação de tabelas mas nada que desse exatamente esse resultado

Comment: Quer atualizar a coluna `points` da `tabela1` com o `points` da `tabela2`?

Comment: eu queria que elas se relacionassem, tipo se uma valor for alterado na coluna points ou na coluna bonus será alterado na outra também

Comment: Basta criar o _trigger_ da mesma forma na `tabela2`, isto se a coluna `bonus` só for atualizada a partir da coluna `points`, caso contrário terá um _loop_ infinito.

Comment: essa é a questão, por que é basicamente assim, a coluna points aumenta com um algoritmo baseado em tempo, de tempo em tempo ela aumenta o valor, e a coluna bonus é tipo um "dinheiro" então toda vez que é realizada operação de compra ela diminui, por isso eu queria que elas tivessem relação, por que ai indiretamente a compra estaria sendo feita com esses "points"

Comment: Aí já não estou a perceber... a coluna `bonus` da `tabela1` é atualizada com o valor da coluna `bonus` da `tabela2` e vice-versa? Assim como a coluna `points`? Fiquei confuso... antes tinha dito que a coluna `bonus` era atualizada com o valor da `points`!

Comment: sim a coluna bonus atualiza com a da points, mas o certo seria que acontece o contrário também, quando alterasse o bonus também alterasse a point, eu devo ter explicado errado

Comment: Se é assim, então criando o mesmo _trigger_ nas duas tabelas vai funcionar! Tem apenas que alterar a tabela no _trigger_ da `tabela2`. Já tentou?

Comment: sim, tentei, mas da um erro falando do nivel maximo de aninhamentos, eu pensei aqui se não seria possivel colocar uma condicional antes desse gatilho, pra ele testar, por exemplo se os dois campos forem diferentes, será ativado o gatilho, se forem iguais não ativa, por que ai quando mudar um o outro muda, e ai vao ficar iguais e o gatilho para de ser acionado, nao fica em loop, isso é possivel ou eu to viajando de mais? kk

Comment: Resposta alterada. Tente da forma que coloquei.

Comment: aquele "origem" ali faz referência ao que exatamente? obrigado pela atenção sempre

Comment: eu não consegui entender como ele para o looping, continua com o mesmo erro =/